# error expected primary-expression before ' ' token

Tags: c++, operadores, sintaxe

Erro na linha 21.

```
#ifndef __STRING_H__
#define __STRING_H__

#pragma warning(disable: 4786)
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const int MAX_RESP = 4;

typedef std::vector<std::string> vstring;


bool isPunc(char c);
void cleanString( std::string &str );
void UpperCase( std::string &str );
void copy(char *array[], vstring &v);

template<typename T>
void shuffle(T &array, size_t size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int index =() % size;
        std::swap(array[i], array[index]);
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: É sua segunda pergunta e ambas são erros de digitação. Seria bom prestar mais atenção ou começar fazendo coisas mais simples até se acostumar mais com a linguagem e os erros apresentados.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando aceitar terá os  15 pontos necessários).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito ter sido só um erro de digitação, já que o operador `%` precisa ter dois operandos, só tem um. Os parenteses estão ali sem sentido. Talvez a intenção era colocar uma expressão lá dentro e seu resultado ser usado como primeiro operando. Ou talvez seja algo mais simples. Troquei os `()` pela variável `i` e compilou, não sei se era a intenção:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void shuffle(T &array, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int index = i % size;
        std::swap(array[i], array[index]);
    }
}
int main() {}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/E5kETb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qyqqngpz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Shuffle.cpp).